# Automapper ignores DTO inside of DTO

Tags: c#, azure, automapper, azure-mobile-services

I am having a Azure Mobile Service and its running fine except i have problems with AutoMapper and DTO's with other DTO's inside of them. Basically they are ignored in the output.

**My Data class:**

```
public class FoodSupplyProvider
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index(IsClustered = true)]
    [Key]
    public int FoodSupplyProviderId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Branche Branche { get; set; }      
}

public class Branche
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index(IsClustered = true)]
    [Key]
    public int BrancheId { get; set; }
    public string BrancheName { get; set; }
}
```

**My DTO classes**

```
public class BrancheDTO : EntityData
{     
    public string BrancheName { get; set; }
}

public class FoodSupplyProviderDTO : EntityData
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BrancheDTO Branche { get; set; }
}
```

I have registered the mappings with the Mapper:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Branche, BrancheDTO>();
cfg.CreateMap<FoodSupplyProvider, FoodSupplyProviderDTO>();
```

**Output:**

When i try to output the FoodSupplyProviderDTO, it is as follows:

```
[{
"id":"2b3fdde5-ba55-4e7f-ae74-5e23abaa7b64",
"name":"FoodSupplyProvider Name 1"
}]
```

I would expect it to be:

```
[{
"id":"2b3fdde5-ba55-4e7f-ae74-5e23abaa7b64",
"name":"FoodSupplyProvider Name 1"
"branche":"The BrancheDTO goes here...."
}]
```

Please note, the expected output is also what the documentation says on my API.

I have checked that the value is not null, i have even tried mapping the Name of the Branche to the Name of the FoodSupplyProviderDTO and that works perfectly fine, except that the Branche is still not present in the output.

***EDIT:***

As @YacoubMassad said, it could be the mapping or the serilization fail. I have tried outputting the mapping and it works as intended. I then tried to json serialize it in code and output the result. That one is as the expected result shown above.

So the problem lies with the WebApi serialising the object for me. Is there anyway i can debug this?

Comment: Did you try providing the BranchName to your input?

Comment: Yes, the Name of the Branch is there.

Comment: You are showing us some JSON output. Are you serializing to JSON? Can you instead show the contents of the result of calling the `Map` method? Maybe the problem is with serialization to JSON.

Comment: I added this config mapping for FoodSupplyProvider

.ForMember(dst => dst.Name, map => map.MapFrom(x => x.Branche.Name))

Which would put the BrancheName in place of the FoodSupplyProviderName

Comment: Just updated the question with my findings on your inputs @YacoubMassad It seems its the WebApi serialization that got a problem.

Comment: when making mapping, usually I put both. try and it for both eg for cfg.CreateMap<Branche, BrancheDTO>(); add cfg.CreateMap<BrancheDTO, Branche>(); Personly I have done DTO nested mapping and its worked. Do that for the other mapping as well.

Comment: Please show the code that fetches the objects. Maybe you need an `Include`.

Comment: I found the problem my self after knowing it wasnt the mapping nor the serializer.

The issue was that since its OData i apparently need the Expand property to expand the related navigation properties.

Anyone can give a good explanation of why this needs to be done even though i have the .include("Branche").

Comment: Could you provide your fix as the answer so others can find it easily?

Comment: I could answer it my self, but i would very much like an explanation of why i need to add the expand. My own answer is too vague of an answer and wouldn't help much to anyone else.